# JavaScript critical error - SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

Tags: javascript, localhost, internet-explorer-11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftfuQ.png)

I am getting JavaScript critical error - SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' when i run my solution. It works fine when i click on continue. However, the file in which this erroro message is displayed, is visible only at run time. How should i resolve this issue. On searching for similar keywords, i got a file reference from where the code appears to be coming which is showing error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IDkN.png)

Comment: `if` instead of `If`.

Comment: Thanks Salman, it worked. Now getting same exception on next line, if you could guide me through, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing If with if worked, getting similar error on next line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSulm.png)